# ConvertFrom-Json getting failed in PrePostDeploymentScript.ps1

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using the following script:

## Run ADF Post-Deployment Powershell Script (Starts Triggers)

```
          - task: AzurePowerShell@5
            displayName: 'ADF Post-Deployment Script'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'SC-Azure-Dev-Subscription' ## This input doesn't accept variables and has to be hard coded
              ScriptType: 'FilePath'
              ScriptPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ArmTemplates/PrePostDeploymentScript.ps1'
              ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ArmTemplates/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(resourceGroupName) -DataFactoryName $(dataFactoryName) -predeployment $false -deleteDeployment $true'
              azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
              pwsh: true
```

This is giving me error at line 680: | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 10

Error: ##[error] Conversion from JSON failed with error: Bad JSON escape sequence: \s. Path 'properties.pipelines[0].parameters.pVMSQLUserName', line 31, position 36. from Line: 680
##[error]Conversion from JSON failed with error: Bad JSON escape sequence: \s. Path 'properties.pipelines[0].parameters.pVMSQLUserName', line 31, position 36.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

I even tried powershell core but still facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

The error might be because of encoding issue. Double-check whether both powershell script and json file are set to UTF-8.